# How to remove 'temporary value dropped while borrowed' in a match

Tags: rust

I'm trying a simple variation of command name and arguments depending on the OS. I have a common set of methods for the stdin/stdout, spawn and expect so I would like not to duplicate them since I may add other OS values later:

```
let cmd = match env::consts::OS {
    "windows" =>
        Command::new("cmd.exe").arg("/c").arg("dir"),
    "linux" =>
        Command::new("ls").arg("-l"),
    _ => {
        panic!("Unrecognized OS");
    }
};
let proc = cmd
    .stdout(Stdio::piped())
    .spawn()
    .expect("Cannot launch the process");
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src\inouts.rs:37:13
   |
35 |     let cmd = match env::consts::OS {
   |         --- borrow later stored here
36 |         "windows" =>
37 |             Command::new("cmd.exe").arg("/c").arg("dir"),
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                    - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |             |
   |             creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

I've tried to use intermediate variables in the `match`, or to declare `cmd` before like this:

```
let mut cmd: &Command;
match env::consts::OS {
    "windows" => {
        cmd = Command::new("cmd.exe").arg("/c").arg("dir")
    }
...
```

but I can't seem to make it work without copying and duplicating the whole part with `proc` within the match. So this works but it start to get very long and repetitive:

```
let proc: Child;
match env::consts::OS {
    "windows" => {
        proc = Command::new("cmd.exe")
            .arg("/c")
            .arg("dir")
            .stdout(Stdio::piped())
            .spawn()
            .expect("Cannot launch the process");
    }
...
```

Is there a way to overcome the lifetime issue and keep something close to the initial code?

I've check many similar *temporary value dropped while borrowed* problems but couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the function [`arg`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.arg) returns a `&mut` to its underlying `Command`, not the owned `Command` itself. So trying to return the return value of `arg` from a match arm does indeed return a reference to a `Command` that exists only within the match arm.

To work around this, you can create the `Command`, store it (owned) in a variable, and then apply the args.

```rust
let mut cmd;
match env::consts::OS {
    "windows" => {
        cmd = Command::new("cmd.exe");
        cmd.arg("/c").arg("dir")
    }
    "linux" => {
        cmd = Command::new("ls");
        cmd.arg("-l")
    }
    _ => {
        panic!("Unrecognized OS");
    }
};

let proc = cmd
    .stdout(Stdio::piped())
    .spawn()
    .expect("Cannot launch the process");
```

Comment: Or create the variable before the `match`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman true, but then I think it'd have to be `mut` outside the match, right? I prefer to have variables be `mut` for as short a time as possible.

Comment: Although in this case I guess it wouldn't matter because it needs to be mutable anyway for `stdout`

Comment: I think I understand now, thanks a lot! I was confused by the difference between `Command::new` and `arg` types (value vs reference) and didn't quite know how to separate them. I did try to make a local variable and return it with `cmd.arg()` but my local cmd was still a reference, so of course it didn't solve the life issue.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman and BallpointBen, it was instructive to see the two versions as well, I looked at the changes above, thanks for that too.

Comment: I edited to save one line, but feel free to roll back.

Comment: Since I'm still learning, is it idiomatic to use the same variable name for temporary and normal variables? Here the 1st "temporary" mutable `cmd` is the same as the one inside the match, while the one receiving the result of the match is the same as the one given to `proc`. I find it slightly confusing but maybe it's just a matter of getting used to it?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I intentionally shadowed the `mut` with a `&mut` to disallow reassignment or moving of the variable since it seemed like OP didn't need that power, but it's definitely a matter of taste.

Comment: @BallpointBen I did the same, just in one line.

Comment: I assume the answer to my earlier question is that it's not idiomatic since usually Rust is on the safe side. So I renamed one variable to avoid the confusion, feel free to roll back if that's indeed the way to do it in Rust.

Comment: I've looked a little more into this, and shadowing a variable seems to be a controversial topic. It's definitely confusing here, so I'll revert to the more explicit code. If someone wants to use it in their own code, that's up to them but I wouldn't use it in an example or on code that is shared.

Comment: @RedGlyph I'm generally not opposed to shadowing, but here it was unnecessary so I removed it.

Comment: @BallpointBen It's even clearer and shorter now. :) Well, it has the merit of showing multiple possibilities in the history here. I'm not sure about shadowing, as I said I'm only learning. Since then I've seen others using it, so I suppose it's a pattern people must simply be aware of. I'm wondering if the root problem is `arg` using a reference instead of moving a value, it seems the latter is preferable in fluent patterns but I don't now if they did that because of a possible issue with change of ownership.